# What language is this? "\H\I'm a header\N\~"

Tags: markup

I am re-writing an ancient (20 yo) interface to meditech. It uses some kind of markup language that I can not find documentation for. Anyone know what it is called or where to find better documentation for it?

What I have figured out so far:

`\H\Visible text\N\` => Visible Text in Bold
`~` => A new line.
`\ZHU\...\N\` => Bold Underline (not sure what z does here maybe indicate multiple flags are present?).
`\ZHIU\...\N\` => Bold Italics Underline (not sure what z does).

Comment: Have you tried your luck here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_markup_languages

Comment: @Marc I did skim that page and looked at all that weren't claiming to be an xml subset but did not find anything close to this. Thanks for the suggestion though.